# Rotating a triangle around a point of origin

Tags: c

Having trouble rotating a triangle around a center point, triangle warps and exceeds it's usual size when trying to rotate.

Here's what I'm working with

```
     x1r = ((x1 - s.x) * cos(radians)) - ((s.y - y1) * sin(radians)) + s.x;
     y1r = ((s.y - y1) * cos(radians)) + ((x1 - s.x) * sin(radians)) + s.y;
     x2r = ((x2 - s.x) * cos(radians)) - ((s.y - y2) * sin(radians)) + s.x;
     y2r = ((s.y - y2) * cos(radians)) + ((x2 - s.x) * sin(radians)) + s.y;
     x3r = ((x3 - s.x) * cos(radians)) - ((s.y - y3) * sin(radians)) + s.x;
     y3r = ((s.y - y3) * cos(radians)) + ((x3 - s.x) * sin(radians)) + s.y;
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: If `s.x == 0` and `s.y==0`, is the transform correct?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).
You need to identify a whole lot of what you've got and what you're up to.  What is `s`; what are `x1`, `y1`, … What is the type of all the variables?  What is an example input that gives bad output, and what is the actual and expected output?

Comment: Have you not heard of 'functions'?   They're useful for avoiding repetition.  Why aren't the vertices of the triangle in the same structure type as the rotation point?  It would make it a whole heap easier to write sensible functions: `new_p1 = rotate(old_p1, s, radians);` to rotate old point `old_p1` about centre `s` by angle `radians`.

Comment: Given [2d](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)#Two_dimensions), I'd expect `x1r = ((x1 - s.x) * cos(radians)) - ((y1 - s.y) * sin(radians)) + s.x; y1r = ((y1 - s.y) * cos(radians)) + ((x1 - s.x) * sin(radians)) + s.y;`  Try that.

Comment: @chux Spot on mate, worked perfectly

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the tips, I'll implement these changes

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect formula used to rotate in the 3 points.  [Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)#Two_dimensions)

```
//x1r = ((x1 - s.x) * cos(radians)) - ((s.y - y1) * sin(radians)) + s.x;
//y1r = ((s.y - y1) * cos(radians)) + ((x1 - s.x) * sin(radians)) + s.y;
  x1r = ((x1 - s.x) * cos(radians)) - ((y1 - s.y) * sin(radians)) + s.x;
  y1r = ((y1 - s.y) * cos(radians)) + ((x1 - s.x) * sin(radians)) + s.y;
```